Message Create event not getting fired in discord.js
const { Client, GatewayIntentBits } = require('discord.js');
require('dotenv').config();

// Initialize Discord Client
const client = new Client({
  intents: [
    GatewayIntentBits.DirectMessages,
    GatewayIntentBits.Guilds,
    GatewayIntentBits.MessageContent,
    GatewayIntentBits.GuildMessages]
});

const channelId = 'xxyy'; 

client.on('ready', () => {
  console.log(`Logged in as ${client.user.tag}!`);
});

client.on('messageCreate', (message) => {
    console.log("HAHAHA")
  if (message.channel.id === channelId) {
    console.log(`New message in channel: ${message.content}`);

    handleNewMessage(message);
  }
});

function handleNewMessage(message) {

  console.log(`Processing message: ${message.content}`);
}


client.login(process.env.DISCORD_BOT_TOKEN);


I have turned the Message Content Intent option on as well. Not sure why message create isnt being triggered. "Ready" event is being fired tho

Have you ensured the bot has the permission required on server?

agreed with @Bobosky, this is the question I would be asking...namely, does the bot have, at a minimum, the ability to read messages in the channel?

Add GuildMessages to your client intents.
